# Suitable Google Cloud Compute instance for Website Hosting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine, hosting, web-hosting

I am new to cloud computing, but want to use it to host a website I am building. The website will be a data analytics site, and each user will interacting with a MySQL database and reading data from text files. I want to be able to accommodate about 500 users at a time. The site will likely have around 1000-5000 users fully scaled. I have chosen GCP, and am wondering if the e2-standard-2 VM instance would be enough to get started. I will also be using a GCP HA MySQL server, I am thinking that 2 vCPU's and 5GB memory will be enough, with 50GB high availability SDD storage. Any suggestions would be appreciated? Also, is there anything other service I will need? Thank you!!

Comment: The answer is who knows. Your question provides no details on the requirements of the static system and per-user requirements for CPU, Memory, storage, Disk I/O, network bandwidth, and required response time. Build a pilot system and benchmark it. At 500 simultaneous users, you should be deploying a load balancer and autoscaling.

Comment: Do you want to perform analytics? have a try to BigQuery. Do you want to scale up and down easily according to the number of user connected? Have a look to serverless solution (especially Cloud Run). New world, new rules ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is irrelevant. On Google Cloud Platform you have real time monitoring for CPU and RAM usage so you if your website is gaining more users you can just upgrade or downgrade your CPU or RAM with 2 or 3 mouse clicks. Start small and upgrade later if you see CPU or RAM is getting close to 100% usage. Start with a N1 chip micro instance 600MB RAM.